# OpenGL combine Textures

Tags: performance, opengl, glfw

I'm programming a 2D-Game in OpenGL and I have to output a level which consists of 20x15 fields.

So I'm currently outputting a texture for each field which is quite slow (300 textures/frame).

But due to the reason that the level never changes, I wondered if it's possible to combine the textures to a big, single texture before the game-loop starts.

Then I would have to output only one texture with 4 Texture Coordinates (0/0)(0/1)(1/1)(1/0) and 4 glVertex2f() which specifies the position in the Window.

This is my current Code for each of the 300 fields:

```
glColor3f(1,1,1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textur);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(textArea.a.x,textArea.b.y);glVertex2f(display.a.x,display.a.y);
    glTexCoord2f(textArea.a.x,textArea.a.y);glVertex2f(display.a.x,display.b.y);
    glTexCoord2f(textArea.b.x,textArea.a.y);glVertex2f(display.b.x,display.b.y);
    glTexCoord2f(textArea.b.x,textArea.b.y);glVertex2f(display.b.x,display.a.y);
glEnd();
```

Note that I have the images for all possible field-types in one .tga-File. So I'm choosing the right one with glTexCoord2f().

The image-File with all Tiles is loaded into

```
GLuint textur;
```

So I bind the same texture for every field.

My target is to decrease CPU-time. Display-Lists didn't work because there is so many data to load in the Graphics Card, that, in the end, display-Lists were even slower.

I also wasn't able to use VBOs because I don't use extensions like GLUT.

So my idea was to generate a single texture which should be quite easy and effective.

I hope you can give me feedback how I can combine textures and if this method would be the easiest one to increase performance

EDIT: that are the OpenGl-Functions I use in my program:

When I start the program, I initialize the window:

```
glfwInit();                     
if( !glfwOpenWindow(windowSize.x,windowSize.y, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW ) ) 
{   glfwTerminate();           
    return;
}
```

And that's all what the game-loop does with OpenG:

```
int main()
{
    //INIT HERE (see code above)

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER,0.1f);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

    long loopStart;//measure loopcycle-time
    do{
        height = height > 0 ? height : 1;
        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );              //set Origin
        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );      //background-color
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();                      
        glOrtho(0,windowSize.x,0,windowSize.y,0,128);   //2D-Mode
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        loopStart=clock();

        //(...) OUTPUT HERE (code see above)

        glfwSwapBuffers();                              //erzeugte Grafikdaten ausgeben

        printf("%4dms -> ",clock()-loopStart);
    }while(...);

    glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: What is you CPU/GPU model, their usage and FPS now? Judging from previous question your problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not very used to OpenGl. I'm currently displaying ~300 textures (I guessed the number) and one loop cylce needs 20-60ms.
My CPU-usage (from one core) is always 100%.
I don't know how many things my GPU does, and how many the CPU, because I'm still a beginner. Do you need a simple example how I print something on the screen?

Comment: What is your CPU and GPU model? Rendering 300 textured quads is a breeze even for 10 year old GPUs

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU @ 2.5GHz, NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS (256MB). Not the best, I know but there must be an easy mehtod on how to speed up the game. I'm not rendering 3D-maps with HD-textures and lots of particle effects, lighning and physics. I just want to display a level with 20*15 fields

Comment: This means you have something very silly in your code, that clogs the performance. Sorry, but SO is not a place to solve such broad problems. It is meant for much more specific questions.

Comment: The piece of code who needs so much time is glfwSwapBuffers();
The rest of the code is processed in 0-1ms.
But I don't know where else I could ask

Comment: OpenGL stacks commands and executes them when it feels right (thats internal implementation details). SwapBuffers command merely orders OpenGL to execute all the stacked commands and render to buffer at once. That is why it takes so long - it executes commands from the stack AND does SwapBuffer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19476/discussion-between-krom-stern-and-maja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified a huge time-killer now. The textures I was using were too large, and the resolution was very unefficient.
The main-texture which included the level sprites had a resolution of 2200x2200 Pixels. So the GPU increased the size to 4096x4096 and calculated it with a huge amount of data.
The image contains 10x10 different Level-Tiles which are outputed on the screen with a resolution of 50x50 pixels each.
So I saved the Tiles-File with a lower resolution (1020 x 1020 Pixels -> each tile=102x102px) and now I have a loop-cycle time of <=15ms.
This isn't perfect, but in comparison with my previous 30-60ms it was a huge progress.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using GLFW. You can add GLEW and GLM and then you should use OpenGL 3.x or higher.

Here is a FULL example, how you can easily draw 2000 Textured Quads (With Alphablending) or more with FPS of 200 or more on a lost budget Laptop. It has only one little Texture, but it will work also with an 4096x4096 Texture Atlas. You get one HUGE Performance-Hit, if the Subtexture Size in the big texture EXACTLY matches the size of your Quad you draw!  You should use 50x50 Pixels also in the Big-Texture! The following Deme-Code here also UPDATES ALL 2000 Quads each frame and send them to the GPU. If you will not have to update them each frame and put the Scroll-Coordinates to the Shader..you will gain performance again. 
If you need no blending...use Alpha-Tests..you will gain again more speed.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw.h"
#include "glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/transform.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

std::ofstream logger("Log\\Ausgabe.txt", (std::ios::out | std::ios::app));

class Vertex
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float tx;
    float ty;
};

class Quad
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;
};

int getHighResTimeInMilliSeconds(bool bFirstRun);
GLuint buildShader();
void addQuadToLocalVerticeArray(Vertex * ptrVertexArrayLocal, Quad *quad, int *iQuadCounter);

int main()
{
    logger << "Start" << std::endl;

    if(!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, 1);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if( !glfwOpenWindow(1366, 768,8,8,8,8,32,32,GLFW_FULLSCREEN) )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    //Init
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    GLuint MatrixID;
    GLuint TextureID;
    GLuint Texture;

    GLuint programID = buildShader();

    //Texture in Video-Speicher erstellen
    GLFWimage img;
    int iResult = glfwReadImage("Graphics\\gfx.tga", &img, GLFW_NO_RESCALE_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,32,32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.Data);
    glfwFreeImage(&img);

    Vertex * ptrVertexArrayLocal = new Vertex[12000];

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexArrayID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 12000, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)1366,0.0f, (float)768, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 Model      = glm::mat4(1.0f); 
    glm::mat4 MVP        = Projection * Model;

    glViewport( 0, 0, 1366, 768 ); 

    MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");

    glUseProgram(programID);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

    int iQuadVerticeCounter=0;

    int iNumOfQuads = 2000;
    Quad * ptrQuads = new Quad[iNumOfQuads];

    //LOCAL VERTICES CHANGES EACH LOOP
    for (int i=0; i<iNumOfQuads; i++)
    {
        ptrQuads[i].width  = 32;
        ptrQuads[i].height = 32;
        ptrQuads[i].x      = (float)(rand() % (1334));
        ptrQuads[i].y      = (float)(rand() % (736));
    }

    int iCurrentTime=0;
    int iFPS=0;
    int iFrames=0;
    int iFrameCounterTimeStart=0;
    int running = GL_TRUE;

    bool bFirstRun=true;

    while( running )
    {
        iCurrentTime = getHighResTimeInMilliSeconds(bFirstRun);
        bFirstRun=false;

        //UPDATE ALL QUADS EACH FRAME!
        for (int i=0; i<iNumOfQuads; i++)
        {
            ptrQuads[i].width  = 32;
            ptrQuads[i].height = 32;
            ptrQuads[i].x      = ptrQuads[i].x;
            ptrQuads[i].y      = ptrQuads[i].y;
            addQuadToLocalVerticeArray(ptrVertexArrayLocal, &ptrQuads[i], &iQuadVerticeCounter);
        }

        //DO THE RENDERING
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexArrayID);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,sizeof(Vertex) * iQuadVerticeCounter, ptrVertexArrayLocal);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertex),BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertex),BUFFER_OFFSET(3*sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, iQuadVerticeCounter);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        iQuadVerticeCounter=0;

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        //END OF DOING THE RENDERING

        running = !glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) &&glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED );

        iFrames++;

        if (iCurrentTime >= iFrameCounterTimeStart + 1000.0f)
        {
            iFPS = (int)((iCurrentTime - iFrameCounterTimeStart) / 1000.0f * iFrames);
            iFrameCounterTimeStart = iCurrentTime;
            iFrames = 0;
            logger << "FPS: " << iFPS << std::endl;
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

int getHighResTimeInMilliSeconds(bool bFirstRun)
{
    if (bFirstRun)
        glfwSetTime(0);

    return (int)((float)glfwGetTime()*1000.0f);
}

GLuint buildShader()
{
    //Hint: Shader in the TXT-File looks like this
    /*std::stringstream ssVertexShader;
    ssVertexShader << "#version 330 core"<< std::endl 
                   <<   "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "out vec2 UV;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "uniform mat4 MVP;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "void main(){"<< std::endl
                   <<   "vec4 v = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);"<< std::endl
                   <<   "gl_Position = MVP * v;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "UV = vertexUV;"<< std::endl
                   <<   "}"<< std::endl;*/


    std::string strVertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream("Shader\\VertexShader.txt", std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            strVertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;

        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    //Hint: Shader in the TXT-File looks like this
    /*std::stringstream ssFragmentShader;
    ssFragmentShader << "#version 330 core\n"
                      "in vec2 UV;\n"
                      "out vec4 color;\n"
                      "uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;\n"
                      "void main(){\n"
                      "color = texture( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgba;\n"
                      "}\n";*/


    std::string strFragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream("Shader\\FragmentShader.txt", std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            strFragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;

        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLuint gluiVertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = strVertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(gluiVertexShaderId, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(gluiVertexShaderId);

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(gluiVertexShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(gluiVertexShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(gluiVertexShaderId, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    std::string strInfoLog = std::string(&VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    GLuint gluiFragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = strFragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(gluiFragmentShaderId, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(gluiFragmentShaderId);

    Result = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv(gluiFragmentShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(gluiFragmentShaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(gluiFragmentShaderId, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    strInfoLog = std::string(&FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    GLuint gluiProgramId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(gluiProgramId, gluiVertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(gluiProgramId, gluiFragmentShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(gluiProgramId);

    Result = GL_FALSE;
    glGetProgramiv(gluiProgramId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(gluiProgramId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( std::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
    glGetProgramInfoLog(gluiProgramId, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    strInfoLog = std::string(&ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(gluiVertexShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(gluiFragmentShaderId);
    return gluiProgramId;
}

void addQuadToLocalVerticeArray(Vertex * ptrVertexArrayLocal, Quad *quad, int *ptrQuadVerticeCounter)
{
    //Links oben
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 1.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);

    //Links unten
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y - quad->height;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 0.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);

    //Rechts unten
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x + quad->width;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y - quad->height;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 1.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 0.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);

    //Rechts unten
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x + quad->width;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y - quad->height;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 1.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 0.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);

    //Rechts oben
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x + quad->width;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 1.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 1.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);

    //Links oben
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].x  = quad->x;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].y  = quad->y;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].z  = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].tx = 0.0f;
    ptrVertexArrayLocal[*ptrQuadVerticeCounter].ty = 1.0f;

    ++(*ptrQuadVerticeCounter);
}
```